# Transactions in Solana

Tags: web3.js, transactions, wallet, javascript

I need to understand and know how **transactions** work in Solana. Whether the transactions are similar or completely different from other blockchains. Also, an example javascript implementation would be helpful, I'd be really happy to see your examples and use cases.

Links, articles or libraries to learn more are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

- you should understand how accounts/PDAs work in solana first
- the signature/signing process and defining the program's address is basically the same as the other chains
- the main difference is txs pass number of accounts with read-only or write flags along with some amount of data to give to the program

  - the data is just bytes usually defined [flag | input_data] where flag defines what function to run (usually programs have multiple different functions to run) and input_data is the data to give to the function
- this is also a good post on the lifecycle of txs: https://jstarry.notion.site/Transaction-confirmation-d5b8f4e09b9c4a70a1f263f82307d7ce